# What's a general rule for this little lambda calculus identity?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I've been fiddling around with a project that does some normalization of lambda calculus(-like) expressions and I stumbled upon that

```
(λ λ ... λ n (n-1) ... 2 1)
```

(De Brujin notation) is just the identity. I've generalized this a little to realize I can do stuff like

```
(λ λ λ λ 4 2 1) = (λ λ 2)
```

So basically if you can identify some character in your expression which is just the variable index *n*, and all variable indices to the left of that point are greater than *n*, and to the right is just descending down the variable indices one at a time to index *1* then you can eliminate all the indices to the right of that character (including that character) and then eliminate the _λ_s from the head of the expression and decrease the remaining indices appropriately.

This feels too haphazard to be the simplest form of this identity though. There must be a cleaner way to express this, and possibly a more general rule.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is just eta-reduction